# Defining capacity of resource in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I have a resource called forklift. Inside the agent Forklift, I have a parameter called Numberfor.

I want to set the direct capacity of forklift to Numberfor. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a good idea. The number of resources should not be defined within the resource agent type, it is not a good setup.

However, if you have to, change the variable `Numberfor` to be `static` in its properties. (you may need to turn on the "[library dev mode](https://anylogic.help/advanced/libraries/library-developer-mode.html#library-developer-mode)"). But only do that if you know what `static` means.

Else, move the variable outside the resource pool and set the pool capacity from there, not from inside the resource agent type